# Dynamically create class members sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, splat

I have a tuple of data:

```
('dave', 23, 'm'),
('alice', 33, 'f'),
('mary', 44, 'f')
```

I have an sqlalchemy base class:

```
class People(Base):
    __tablename__='people'
```

I want to be able to dynamically create columns/fields for this class using data from the tuple above

the end result would be:

```
class People(Base):
    __tablename__='people'

    dave = Column(String)
    alice = Column(String)
    mary = Column(String)
```

though, i can't figure out how do use the splat operator to create the fields..

Comment: Usually you'd have `name`, `age`, and `sex` columns instead in your `people` table, and you'd store the tuples as rows of that table.

Comment: my example was poor. i have an excel doc with column_name,type and i want to be able to dynamically create columns like `col['column_name'] = Column(col['type']) for col in columns`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768607/dynamic-class-creation-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: You can create table with dynamic fields and then map to one of the ORM class.`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574105/sqlalchemy-dynamic-mapping/2575016#2575016`

Answer (score 0):

The solution -

```
edtl_schematic = {
    '__tablename__': 'fedex_shipments'
}

for c in cols:
    (column, db_name, db_type) = c
    edtl_schematic[c[1]] = Column(db_name, eval(db_type),primary_key=True if db_name=='ship_trk_num' else False)


ExtendedShipmentDetail=type('ExtendedShipmentDetail',(Base,),edtl_schematic)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

`cols` is a tuple that contains information loaded from an excel sheet that has the columns `Sheet Column | DB Name | DB Type` where `DB Name` is the name i want the excel sheet column to have in the DB, and `DB Type` is a sqlalchemy type. Whether this is the correct way of doing this or not, it works..